# bquote: How to include an expression saved as a string object?

Tags: string, r, expression

My goal is to annotate a plot with the slope of a best-fit line and label the units of the slope, where the label is saved as a separate string object. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get `bquote()` to convert a string object into an expression, and combine it with other evaluated statements.

A demonstration:

```
# example data:
x <- c(1:20)                   # x units: time
y <-  x * rnorm(20, 10, 2)     # y units: length per time

unit.label <- "L%.%T^-2"       # label for slope of best fit line 
lm1 <- summary(lm(y ~ x))

plot(y ~ x)
```

The problem occurs when I try to annotate the plot. I can get bquote() to display the slope:

```
text(median(x), min(y), bquote(slope: .(round(lm1$coefficients[2], 2))) )
```

I can also get `bquote()` to show the slope's units:

```
plot(y ~ x)
text(median(x), min(y), bquote(.(parse(text = unit.label))) )
```

But I'm unable to combine the label and the slope into a single `bquote()` statement:

```
plot(y ~ x)
text(median(x), min(y), bquote(slope: .(round(lm1$coefficients[2], 2)) 
.(parse(text = unit.label))) ) 
# Error: unexpected symbol in "text(median(x), min(y), bquote(slope: 
# .(round(lm1$coefficients[2], 2)) ."
```

Using `paste()`, the unit label appears along with the slope, but the label isn't read as an expression:

```
plot(y ~ x)
text(median(x), min(y), bquote(slope: .(paste(round(lm1$coefficients[2], 2), 
as.expression(unit.label))))
)
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it a simple syntax problem in my bquote command?
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: +1 for following the post guidelines and using a reproducible example. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) parse char string** Create the character string desired (ensuring that it represents an expressoin that is syntactically valid in R) and then parse it.  Here `main_s` is the character string:

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x)

main_s <- paste("slope:", round(coef(fm)[2], 2), "~", unit.label)
plot(0, main = parse(text = main_s))
```

The statement setting `main_s` could alternately be replaced with the following `sprintf` statement which is arguably more readable:

```
main_s <- sprintf("slope: %.2f ~ %s", coef(fm)[2], unit.label)
```

**2) bquote** The above is probably the most straight-forward way to handle this but to use `bquote` try this where `unit.label_c` is a call object and `fm` is as defined above:

```
unit.label_c <- parse(text = unit.label)[[1]]
plot(0, main = bquote(slope: .(round(coef(fm)[2], 2)) ~ .(unit.label_c)))
```

In either case we get this:

[image: screenshot]

**UPODATE** Added (2).  Also some improvements and corrections.

Answer (score 4):

I like to build the expression first using `substitute` and never storing parts of the expression as character vectors. This will work

```
plotlabel = substitute( slope~L%.%T^-2, 
    list(slope=round(lm1$coefficients[2], 2)))
plot(y ~ x)
text(median(x), min(y), plotlabel)
```

But as to why `bquote` did not work is an interesting question. Clearly the two types of objects you are trying to replace are different classes. In the case of the slope value, that's a basic character, in the case if the unit.label, you're calling parse which returns an expression. To me it seems tricky to get expressions into `bquote`. It's odd that it works all by itself.

```
bquote(.(parse(text = unit.label))) #works -> expresion
bquote(.(parse(text = unit.label))+1) #doesn't work -> call
```

The former returns an "expression", the latter returns a "call". Really we'd like the second one to return an expression as well, but it's trying to add "+1" to the expression already returned by parse and that just doesn't seem to work nicely.